# Enviar tweets con imagen en API de Twitter V1.1 no está funcionando

Tags: twitter-api

Tengo 2 cuentas de Twitter. La primera y mas antigua tiene creada la app de Twitter hace muchísimo tiempo y cuando envío tweets desde PHP con una determinada función sacada de Internet funciona perfectamente.

Hace un par de meses decidí crear la app para la segunda cuenta de Twitter para poder enviar tweets con imágenes desde php también, así que simplemente modifiqué las claves específicas de la aplicación nueva en la misma función que uso para la otra.

Pues bien, no hay manera de que funcione. Lo sigue haciendo con la primera cuenta y no funciona con la segunda. La única diferencia que veo es que la segunda app se creó existiendo ya la versión 2.0 de la API de Twitter, pero tengo activado OAuth 1.0a y aún así no hay manera de que funcione. Me está volviendo loco el por qué y sinceramente, con mis conocimientos actuales de programación, no llego a entender como funciona la versión 2.0 para hacer lo mismo.

Os dejo la función que utilizo para ver si se os ocurre el motivo de por qué funciona con una APP antigua y no con la nueva. Un saludo y gracias.

```js
function tweet($message,$image) {
    // add the codebird library
    require_once('codebird-php/src/codebird.php');
    // note: consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, and accessTokenSecret all come from your twitter app at https://apps.twitter.com/
    CodebirdCodebird::setConsumerKey("XXX", "XXXX");
    $cb = CodebirdCodebird::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken("XXXX", "XXXX");
    //build an array of images to send to twitter
    $reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
        'media' => $image
    ));
    //upload the file to your twitter account
    $mediaID = $reply->media_id_string;
    //build the data needed to send to twitter, including the tweet and the image id
    $params = array(
        'status' => $message,
        'media_ids' => $mediaID
    );
    //post the tweet with codebird
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
}
```